# Postgresql get count of items based on the condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, postgresql-9.4, having-clause

I have a table something like this

fruit -   state
-------------------
apple - new
apple - okay
apple - okay
apple - bad
banana -    new
banana -    okay
banana -    bad
orange -    new
orange  - okay
orange -    okay
orange  - okay
orange  - okay
orange  - okay

I want to get the items that are not in 'bad' state and how many times it was 'okay'.Something like this:

fruit - okaycount 
----------------------
orange  -   5

Apple and banana are in 'bad' state at this point.
and oranges are okay five times(not counting New state).

I tried this one and it is not working as it is giving apple and banana's 'okay' state as well.

```
select * from (select fruit, count(fruit) AS okaycount
from fruits
where  state='okay'
group by fruit) as din
order by din.okaycount desc
limit 10;
```

Tried this one as well. Did not work.

```
SELECT distinct ndt.fruit, COUNT( ndt.fruit ) as okaycount
FROM(select * from fruits where fruit in (select distinct correlationid 
from fruits
where wcsstatus!='bad')) as ndt
GROUP BY ndt.fruit
HAVING count(*) > 3;
```

Comment: What do you mean "at this point"?  SQL tables represent unordered sets.

Comment: what I meant was the Apple and bananas need not be picked.
but the query I used was picking up apples and banana as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, I would phrase this with a filtering count and boolean aggregation in the `having` clause:

```
select fruit, count(*) filter(where status = 'okay') cnt
from fruits
group by fruit
having not bool_or(status = 'bad')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the results you want, you can use:

```
select fruit, sum( (status = 'okay')::int )
from fruit
group by fruit
having sum( (status = 'bad')::int ) = 0;
```